# How do I create "mapping" matrix based on searchsorted result in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to create an MxN matrix based on two input arrays (XI and X), where each row has 1 if the column represents the result of search sorted for that row's X value (within XI).

Code:

```
import numpy as np

XI = np.array([1., 2., 4., 5., 7.])
X = np.array([6.5, 2.2, 1.4, 4., 3.7, 3.9, 0.1, 5.3, 10.2])

def bmap(xi, x):
    i = np.searchsorted(xi, x, side="right") - 1
    result_shape = (x.shape[0], xi.shape[0])
    result = np.zeros(result_shape)
    for row, column in enumerate(i):
        if -1 < column < xi.shape[0] - 1:
            result[row,column] = 1.
    return result

bmap(XI, X)
```

Expected Output:

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

How do I do this using only vectorized operations (e.g. excluding the enumeration of `i` and the bounds checking)? Bonus points for something that can be used in TensorFlow as well (since, ultimately, I'm trying to port this over to TensorFlow so I can take advantage of algorithmic differentiation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you just want to convert the indices `i` to positions in an array (one per row), unless that index is negative or in the last column.

```
i = np.searchsorted(xi, x, side="right") - 1
# array([ 3,  1,  0,  2,  1,  1, -1,  3,  4], dtype=int64)
```

Creat your output array and a mask of valid values:

```
out=np.zeros([x.size, xi.size])
valid = (i>-1)&(i<xi.shape[0] - 1)
#valid: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True, False])
```

Use `valid` mask to index rows and `i` (where valid) serves as indices for columns:

```
out[valid, i[valid]] = 1
```